# Manually deployed Sharepoint workflow won't visible inside the Site Collection Workflows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow-foundation, moss, sharepoint-workflow

I'm developing a three level workflow to MOSS 2007, I published it to our test environment with **stsadm installfeature** and **activatefeature** and it works perfectly.

[I followed this article to publish the new workflow.](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/workflow/how-to-manually-deploy-visual-studio-2005-workflow-sharepoint.htm)

After the test session I tried to publish it to the live environment which is the same environment, and the new workflow is visible inside the **Site Settings** > **Site Feature** (Status is Active), but won't show inside the **Site Settings** > **Site Collection Workflows**.

I don't know what is the problem, because on the test environment everything works fine.

Some informations about the system:
Windows 2003 server
Sharepoint (MOSS 2007 with SP3)
Visual Studio 2008

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I report this problem to MS Offical Support and after a few days and some phone calls they solved my problem.

I made a big mistake, I generated a new GUID for the Feature Id attribute, but I forgot to generete new GUID for the Workflow Id and it causes the error, because there were two WF with the same GUID. After I changed it, it started to work well.

```
<Feature Id="Generate new GUID !!!!"
Title="Default Title"
Description="This feature is a workflow that ..."
Version="12.0.0.0"
Scope="Site"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<ElementManifests>
<ElementManifest Location="workflow.xml" />
</ElementManifests>
<Properties>
<Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="true" />
</Properties>
</Feature>

<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Workflow
Name="My Workflow"
Description="This workflow ..."
Id="Generate new GUID !!!!"
CodeBesideClass="ProjectName.Workflow1"
CodeBesideAssembly="ProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=publicKeyToken"
TaskListContentTypeId="0x000"
AssociationUrl="_layouts/MyAssocForm.aspx"
InstantiationUrl="_layouts/MyInitForm.aspx"
ModificationUrl="_layouts/MyModForm.aspx"
StatusUrl="_layouts/WrkStat.aspx">
<Categories/>
<MetaData>
<Modification_GUID_Name>
Name of Modification
</Modification_GUID_Name>
</MetaData>
</Workflow>
</Elements>
```